# Only certain video files in <video> tag are played on a white screen

Tags: electron, html5-video, chromium

Only certain video files in  tag are played on a white screen.
Other files with the same extension work well.
It plays when you convert the file to another extension. (ex. mov -> mp4)

[image]

```
<video controls autoPlay width="100%" height="100%">
 <source src={videoUrl} />
</video>
```

I think it has something to do with the HEVC codec.

my electron version 18.0.4

1. Add meta to html

http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="media-src *;">

2. The video url works well if you do it on Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share my solution.

Just a chromium version problem.

update v100 -> v110

Answer (score 0):

Make sure electron >= 22 (chromium 107 add hevc hw decoding support) will solve your problem.